# Displaying ViewController on other Viewcontroller view

Tags: ios, constraints, uipageviewcontroller

I am using Apple Page-based application template. In rootviewController I add a view that is not full screen as shown below on the image. The white area is the added view in RootviewController

[image]

This is the DataViewController I want to display in RootviewControllers's View (the image below)

[image]

And If I run it in simulator it shows the image below, I have played with the constraints but, still it shows the white stripe that I can not get rid of. Is the DataViewController size somehow fixed... I have no idea, where I should start to fix this problem or is there a better way to solve it?
[image]

Comment: what are the active constraints? are you sure you pinned the view to the 4 sides? or pinned it to two sides and set its width and height

Comment: I did pin both sides, bottom and set height of the view, but still the white stripe appears. The image of set constrains is here in here : https://gyazo.com/447f98b97113e9adeea5f2c5540b72c6

Comment: i dont think you have to set height for the behaviour you expect. try removing height..although that doesn't sound like the problem which causes white space on the side...

Comment: If I don't set any constraints at all then no white stripe is appeared, then its like this:
https://gyazo.com/db470649e8ca7f081f8aa66fddd6c7ce

Comment: and this is how you want it? this will work without constraints if your intended device is only iphone 5s (or 5 because of same screen size)..

Comment: how do you add the DataViewController's view as subview to RootViewController?

Comment: No, the target devices are all the iphones(4s,5, 5s etc)
Code is here: https://gyazo.com/2b45a3af4de9679082224a60cec83370

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106452/discussion-between-karl-kivi-and-meharoof-najeeb).

Comment: Okay; thank you, I managed to fix the problem - well,  I tried to set constraints to my view in main.storyboard while setting the view's frame in code and that caused the mess and the white ( or the view's bg color) stripe